# Will a 63 silverado cab work on a c10 frame?

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, frame, c10, cabin

Working on a 63 build I have a custom frame that has 63 c10 mounts but I've found what the vin identifies as a 63 chevy silverado and I'm wondering if the cab will use the same body mounts as the c10? Any cab issues I might face?

Comment: It should. Back in the early 60's they used a lot of the same parts between the vehicles. I doubt there was any difference in the frames between a C10 and a Silverado (though I don't know for sure). If you're *really serious* about this, just measure the mounts and see.

Comment: Measure and you will know. Even make templates to check.